# CSS image as background

Tags: html, css

I want to use an transparent image for my html background. located at bottom left of `.sidebar`
the background color has to follow the sidebar background. the image should stay there whenever the page or sidebar is scrolled.

[image]

the following is my css

```
.wrapper .sidebar .logopic {
    background: #276eff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 700px;
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(20% - 9%);
    background: url("https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Colorful-google-logo-design-on-transparent-PNG-1.png")bottom left no-repeat;
    background: transparent;
    background-size: 300px 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 90vh;
}
```

Please advise. and this is the fiddle [css](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/qcgx18rb/10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code instead

CSS

```
.logopic {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: bottom;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<img url="https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/12/Colorful-google-logo-design-on-transparent-PNG-1.png" alt="img"class="logopic">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2cux6fmh/5/

Comment: Thanks, I edited filddle https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/qcgx18rb/16/ the picture is not showing up